# How to smooth non-linear regression curve in R

Tags: r, non-linear-regression

So I'm asked to obtain an estimate theta of the variable Length in the MASS package. The code I used is shown below, as well as the resulting curve. Somehow, I don't end up with a smooth curve, but with a very "blocky" one, as well as some lines between points on the curve. Can anyone help me to get a smooth curve?

```
utils::data(muscle,package = "MASS")
Length.fit<-nls(Length~t1+t2*exp(-Conc/t3),muscle,
                start=list(t1=3,t2=-3,t3=1))
plot(Length~Conc,data=muscle)
lines(muscle$Conc, predict(Length.fit))
```

Image of the plot: [image]
.

Edit: as a follow-up question:
If I want to more accurately predict the curve, I use nonlinear regression to predict the curve for each of the 21 species. This gives me a vector

```
theta=(T11,T12,...,T21,T22,...,T3).
```

I can create a for-loop that plots all of the graphs, but like before, I end up with the blocky curve. However, seeing as I have to plot these curves as follows:

```
for(i in 1:21) {
  lines(muscle$Conc,theta[i]+theta[i+21]*
        exp(-muscle$Conc/theta[43]), col=color[i])
  i = i+1
}
```

I don't see how I can use the same trick to smooth out these curves, since muscle$Conc still only has 4 values.

Edit 2:
I figured it out, and changed it to the following:

```
lines(seq(0,4,0.1),theta[i]+theta[i+21]*exp(-seq(0,4,0.1)/theta[43]), col=color[i])
```

Comment: True. I edited it with my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the output of `cbind(muscle$Conc, predict(Length.fit))`, you'll see that many points are repeated and that they're not sorted in order of `Conc`. `lines` just plots the points in order and connects the points, giving you multiple back-and-forth lines. The code below runs `predict` on a unique set of ordered values for `Conc`.

```
plot(Length ~ Conc,data=muscle)
lines(seq(0,4,0.1),
      predict(Length.fit, newdata=data.frame(Conc=seq(0,4,0.1))))
```

[image]

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks!